# Google Map api v2 Marker not moving until I rotate the phone and the map "refreshes"

Tags: java, android, google-maps, location, marker

I have the following code :

public class MapsActivity extends FragmentActivity  implements
        GoogleApiClient.ConnectionCallbacks,
        GoogleApiClient.OnConnectionFailedListener,
        LocationListener {

```
private GoogleMap mMap; // Might be null if Google Play services APK is not available.


// LogCat tag
private static final String TAG = MapsActivity.class.getSimpleName();

private final static int PLAY_SERVICES_RESOLUTION_REQUEST = 1000;

private Location mLastLocation;

// Google client to interact with Google API
private GoogleApiClient mGoogleApiClient;

// boolean flag to toggle periodic location updates
private boolean mRequestingLocationUpdates = false;

private LocationRequest mLocationRequest;

// Location updates intervals in sec
private static int UPDATE_INTERVAL = 5000; // 10 sec
private static int FASTEST_INTERVAL = 1000; // 5 sec
private static int DISPLACEMENT = 5; // 10 meters

private boolean checkPlayServices() {
    int resultCode = GooglePlayServicesUtil
            .isGooglePlayServicesAvailable(this);
    if (resultCode != ConnectionResult.SUCCESS) {
        if (GooglePlayServicesUtil.isUserRecoverableError(resultCode)) {
            GooglePlayServicesUtil.getErrorDialog(resultCode, this,
                    PLAY_SERVICES_RESOLUTION_REQUEST).show();
        } 
        return false;
    }
    return true;
}

protected synchronized void buildGoogleApiClient() {
    mGoogleApiClient = new GoogleApiClient.Builder(this)
            .addConnectionCallbacks(this)
            .addOnConnectionFailedListener(this)
            .addApi(LocationServices.API).build();
}

protected void createLocationRequest() {
    mLocationRequest = new LocationRequest();
    mLocationRequest.setInterval(UPDATE_INTERVAL);
    mLocationRequest.setFastestInterval(FASTEST_INTERVAL);
    mLocationRequest.setPriority(LocationRequest.PRIORITY_HIGH_ACCURACY);
    mLocationRequest.setSmallestDisplacement(DISPLACEMENT);
}


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_maps);
    setUpMapIfNeeded();

    // First we need to check availability of play services
    if (checkPlayServices()) {

        // Building the GoogleApi client
        buildGoogleApiClient();

        createLocationRequest();
    }
}

@Override
protected void onResume() {
    super.onResume();
    setUpMapIfNeeded();
    mGoogleApiClient.connect();
}

@Override
protected void onPause() {
    super.onPause();
    if (mGoogleApiClient.isConnected()) {//eliminando updates y desconectando
        LocationServices.FusedLocationApi.removeLocationUpdates(mGoogleApiClient, this);
        mGoogleApiClient.disconnect();
    }

}

@Override
protected void onStop() {
    super.onStop();
    if (mGoogleApiClient.isConnected()) {
        mGoogleApiClient.disconnect();
    }
}




private void setUpMapIfNeeded() {
    // hacer una pruba de null para saber si mMap esta activo
    if (mMap == null) {
        // obtener el mapa por SupportMapFragment.
        mMap = ((SupportMapFragment) getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.map))
                .getMap();
        // verificar si el mapa esta activo
        if (mMap != null) {
            setUpMap();
        }
    }
}

/**
 * This is where we can add markers or lines, add listeners or move the camera. In this case, we
 * just add a marker near Africa.
 * <p/>
 * This should only be called once and when we are sure that {@link #mMap} is not null.
 */
private void setUpMap() {
    }

@Override
public void onConnected(Bundle bundle) {
    Log.i(TAG, "Servicios de localización activados");
    Location location = LocationServices.FusedLocationApi.getLastLocation(mGoogleApiClient);
    if (location == null) { //Se llama cuando no hay una ultima localización disponible
        LocationServices.FusedLocationApi.requestLocationUpdates(mGoogleApiClient, mLocationRequest, this);
    }
    else {
        handleNewLocation(location);
    }
}

@Override
public void onConnectionSuspended(int i) {
    Log.i(TAG, "Servicios de localización suspendidos. Favor de reconectar.");
}

//Metodo para cuando la localización cambia
@Override
public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {
    handleNewLocation(location);
}

@Override
public void onConnectionFailed(ConnectionResult connectionResult) {

        Log.i(TAG, "Servicio de localización falló con el siguiente codigo: "+connectionResult.getErrorCode());
    }



private void handleNewLocation(Location location) {

    mLastLocation = LocationServices.FusedLocationApi
            .getLastLocation(mGoogleApiClient);

    if (mLastLocation != null) {
        double latitude = mLastLocation.getLatitude();
        double longitude = mLastLocation.getLongitude();
        LatLng latLng = new LatLng(latitude, longitude);


        //añadir un nuevo marker con la posición de la variable latLng
        MarkerOptions camion = new MarkerOptions()
                .position(latLng)
                .title("Camión");
        mMap.addMarker(camion);
        mMap.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLng(latLng));
        CameraUpdate zoom=CameraUpdateFactory.zoomTo(19);
        mMap.animateCamera(zoom);
    }
}
```

I want the marker to move when the phone moves but it doesnt move until i rotate the phone and the screen rotates then the map refreshes and the marker move to my actual position, also sometimes the marker duplicates and if i rotate the phone the duplicated marker dissapears.
Any idea why this is happening? Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you see when markers get duplicated is in fact the system working:

1. First time you get a position, a marker gets added, all cool.
2. If a new position comes, you call `handleNewLocation(location)`and a new marker gets added on: `mMap.addMarker(camion);`

To avoid that, use always the same marker and update its location if necessary:

```
if(mCamionMarker == null){ 
    mCamionMarker = mMap.addMarker(camion);
}else{
    mCamionMarker.setPosition(latLng);
}
```

Those other times when you do not get updates are because the api considers it can't provide you with a better location.

Consider disconnecting and cleaning up either in onResume or onStop but not on both.

Comment: Thank you so much Jose! but what do you mean by disconnecting and cleaning up? you mean rewrite the code in onResume or onStop?

Comment: Np! Yeah, currently the code in your onStop is unnecessary, since the process will visit onPause first and will take care of disconnecting Google client.

Comment: Jose I know that this may annoy you but I need to finish this project and i have no idea about how to fix this errors could you maybe help me via email?

Comment: You will not have a hard time finding me in G+.